# Why my navigator is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I have this structure, where I have a list of `MyComponent`:

```
class MyComponent extends Component 
{
    props: { navigation: Object, data: Object };

    ShowScreenB(data: Object){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {data});    
    }

    render() 
    { 
        return (
                <Menu>
                    <MenuTrigger>  <Text> Menu </Text>  </MenuTrigger>
                    <MenuOptions>
                        <MenuOption onSelect={() => this.ShowScreenB.bind(this, this.props.data)}  text='Show Screen B' />
                    </MenuOptions>
                </Menu>
        );
    }
}

class MyScreen extends Component 
{   
    render()     
    {
        let renderRow = (row) => { return (<MyComponent data= {row} navigation= {this.props.navigation} /> );}

        return (
            <View >
                <ListView dataSource={this.state.DataSource} renderRow={renderRow.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But `ShowScreenB()` does not go to the other screen.

I also tried to prepare the navigator in `MyScreen` class and then pass it as a function to `MyComponent`. But also does not work:

```
class MyComponent extends Component 
{
    props: { OnPress: Function, data: Object };

    render() 
    { 
        return (
                <Menu>
                    <MenuTrigger>  <Text> Menu </Text>  </MenuTrigger>
                    <MenuOptions>
                        <MenuOption onSelect={() => this.OnPress.bind(this)}  text='Show Screen B' />
                    </MenuOptions>
                </Menu>
        );
    }
}

class MyScreen extends Component 
{   
    ShowScreenB(data: Object){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {data});    
    }

    render()     
    {
        let renderRow = (row) => { return (<MyComponent data= {row} OnPress= {this.ShowScreenB.bind(this, row)} /> );}

        return (
            <View >
                <ListView dataSource={this.state.DataSource} renderRow={renderRow.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Edit: `Menu` is a [PopUp Menu](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/doc/examples.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `ShowScreenB()`.

Right now you are just binding it:

```
onSelect={() => this.ShowScreenB.bind(this, this.props.data)}
```

[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) doesn't call the function. All it does it bind it to the given context. You need to actually call `ShowScreenB()` so your navigation code executes. For example:

```
onSelect={() => { this.ShowScreenB.bind(this); this.ShowScreenB(this.props.data); }}
```

**Edit to answer comment since it won't fit in a comment:**

That's because removing `( ) =>` makes it so all you have is the `{ }` syntax leftover. `{ }` means to evaluate what is inside the brackets. Take a look at what is written in the link in my answer. The return value of `bind` is:

> A copy of the given function with the specified this value and initial arguments.

So the expression `{ this.ShowScreenB.bind(this) }` will evaluate the return value; hence calling the navigation function. What I posted above was simply one example of what you could do. You could just as well write it as `onSelect={() => this.ShowScreenB.bind(this)()}` and it would work as well. If you're having trouble with this, you should also brush up on how [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) work.

Comment: Thanks and it works if I remove `() =>` from `MenuOption` like this:  `<MenuOption onSelect= {this.OnPress.bind(this)}  text='Show Screen B' />`

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Edited to answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the arrow functions link! I agree that I need it :)